# Convergence on all Borel sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I'm doing the following exercise:

> Let $\{ f_n \}$ be a sequence of measurable real-valued functions on $[0, 1]$ that is uniformly bounded. Show for each Borel subset there's a subsequence $k_n$ such that $\int_A f_{k_n}$ converges. Do the same for a countable family of Borel sets, then for all Borel sets.

The first two are pretty straightforward: uniform boundedness and $[0, 1]$ as the domain show the integrals are inside an interval, so by compactness we have a convergent subsequence.

Next, I can do the "diagonal method": enumerate the sets, find a subsequence for the first and replace the sequence by it. Next, for the second, find a subsequence and replace the sequence by it, and so on... Then collect all diagonal indexes.

I'm stuck on the third item. My idea: use second item on all rational intervals (semi-closed, open, etc.), then try to show the set of Borel subsets for which the integral converges is a $\sigma$-algebra. However, I'm having some trouble. I know it has all complements, but I don't know how to deduce the intersection case. I can't see any convergence relation between $\int_A f_n$, $\int_B f_n$ and $\int_{A \cap B} f_n$. Without this I can't proceed to unions. Actually, I even don't know if it is enough to choose the subsequence with only the rational intervals in mind.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The  basic approximation theorem of Measure Theory (Ref. Theorem D, p. 56 of Halmos' Measure Theory) shows that given any Borel set $B$ in $[0,1]$ there exists a seqeuence of sets $(B_n)$ such that each $B_n$ is a finite disjoint union of intervals and $m (B\Delta B_n) \to 0$. ($m$ denotes Lebesgue measure). By further approximation we may take these intervals to have rational end points. You can now finish the proof using the fact that $|\int_B f_{k_n} -\int_{B_m} f_{k_n}| \leq C m(B\Delta B_m)$ where $C$ is a bound for $f_n$'s.